# Multiple Lines in one Graph?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I tried much way to make three lines in my Graph, but I didn't find a reasonable one, every time something get wrong. Have someone an idea how to make them and please without using path bc it don't display them as I want.
Here how they must look like the photo on the top left
http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/rescaled512/2646684_1756-6649-9-2-5.png.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show your code that you attempted. You will need, at a basic level, 3 individual series with data in them. Have you looked at the API or the examples on the HighCharts site?

Comment: yes, actually i tried with path, but it is not good and also to put some line under series option in the graph but it dont display good the graph like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-regression/ it shows two zero in my graph which is wrong

Comment: Okay, not sure what you mean by "path". The 2 "0" values on the axis labels are for the x and y axis. Similar to your example chart where there are two "0.6" values. Also not sure what you mean about "put some line under series option". Can you post your code that you are trying to fix.

Comment: With Path i mean to not draw on the graph like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-path-on-chart/  and with "put some line ..." i mean in the options series to write many time line like here http://jsfiddle.net/ZqV7C/1/, and for the two zero it dont look good and i dont think that some poeple will understand it bc we r familar with only one zero in a graph

Comment: How does your jsfiddle.net/ZqV7C/1 example not meet your needs (other than the two "0"s)?

Comment: actually the two "0" r the problem now bc i thought in the begening that the two "0" came bc i did something wrong with the lines, so now how can i let only one 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not show any label on the x or y axis you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/ZqV7C/2/):

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.value !== 0) {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am testing that the yAxis value is not "0". If it passes then we show the label on the yAxis.

Comment: no it's more complicated, just a normal Graph aht i need.It's strange bc with other type of Graphs evrything is ok but only with scatter plot is like that.

Comment: So, the example fiddle jsfiddle.net/ZqV7C/1 is not what you are doing? How does the label formatter listed not meet your requirement to not show the "0" on the origin of the chart twice? What are you actual requirements?

Comment: i wanna that the graph have one common "0" for both axis like here http://www.ncsu.edu/chemistry/resource/excel/excel.html

Comment: They do have a common "0". It is just formatting that makes it look like they do not. If you go to my example you can see that the origin is still the same only now I am only showing the xAxis "0" label and hiding the yAxis "0" label.

Comment: for the usability is not perfect, we learned all over the world one type of Graph with common 0 so for one newbie who wanna read fast the graph will think that -0,5 is +0,5 bc he think that evrything on the right begins from the Yaxis

Comment: Now I understand. Well, easy. Set your xAxis `min` to 0 instead of -0.5. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/ZqV7C/3/